# Spring dependency not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies

I'm very new to Spring, and also Maven. I'm following along with the book **Spring Start Here** because it seems friendly. The very first project asks us to add a *spring-context* dependency to a new project (using maven). I'm using the Intellij Idea community version to follow along, as suggested in the book. But on following the instructions to add the dependency I get an error: **Dependency 'org.springframework:spring-context:' not found**

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.myspring</groupId>
    <artifactId>start</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

I think the idea is to add spring dependencies one by one in order to see their purpose. The autocompletion in idea shows an error for the lines

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
```

- I have already tried updating the maven>repositories in the ide settings but still get the same error.
- Also, I found the page https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context which seems to suggest I have used the correct `groupId` and `artifactId` names

Edit: I just removed the empty version tag in the dependency.

Comment: You need to specify the version using `version`
Most people you see don't specify a version because they inherit `spring-boot-starter-parent` using parent

Comment: Oh, that worked! Thanks @Jilliss I thought, it would automatically take the latest one that resolves correctly.
If you want, please post an answer and I can mark that as the correct one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maven usually requires the `version` tag to specify the version
Most cases where no version is specified are when the project inherits pom files
For example

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Unlike `npm` and `pip`, it does not automatically select the latest version